# Marketo create leads via REST API - is the result array in the same order as the batched records in the request?

Tags: marketo

When sending batched records to the "Sync Leads" endpoint, if the request itself was successful, there is a `result` array returned with the success or failure of each record. Unfortunately in the case of a record-level failure, there won't be any identifying information I can use in the response to reference back to the `input` collection that I sent in the request as a batch.

I need to tie back any "skipped" results to the record in the request that failed to process. Is the `result` array in the same order as the collection of `input` records I posted in the batch? This would allow me to reference the `input` records by index of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to [Marketo's Developer documentation](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/#create_and_update) on querying marketable people.

You should be able to correlate the order of your submission with the sequence number returned.

> ... calls to create or update lead database objects will return an
>   **seq** field in each object in the results array.  The number listed **corresponds to the order** of the updated record in the request made.  Each item will also return the value of the idField for the object
>   type, and a status.  The status field will indicate one of **“created,”
>   “updated,” or “skipped.”**  If the status is skipped, then there will
>   also be a corresponding **“reasons”** array with one or more reason
>   objects that includes a code and a message, indicating why a record
>   was skipped.

Comment: The paragraph you cite reads: "Other than the leads API, calls to create or update...", 
Isn't that explicitly saying that this information doesn't apply to the leads API?